# Checking user is a member of a given AD Group (ASP Classic)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, active-directory, kerberos

I have an legacy application that is still going strong, based on ASP Classic. To secure the application, I'm checking the logged-in user is a member of a certain AD group, and I'm returning a little useful information (e.g. full name, email address etc).

This should be fairly routine and some years ago, I changed from my original approach (now forgotten) to my current one. It was a bit fiddly to implement because it crossed a number of technical areas that I knew relatively little about, but I got the system working OK.

Cue several server moves later (each one being a battle to re-implement the system), and I'm not faced with another move or three. So far I am struggling to get things working. My code, I assume is still sound, but it is the server configuration that is the problem. Permissions, SETSPNs, Kerberos delegation etc...

So the question is, what do I do to make this work, or alternatively, is there another approach I can take. My target servers are standard Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2 boxes, within the same AD domain.

My ASP is as follows:

```
If Session("UID") = "" then

Dim oWshNetwork, oADSysInfo, oCurrentUser, sUserName, sComputerName
Dim sGroups

Set oWshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Set oADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

Set oCurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & oADSysInfo.UserName)

Session("UID") = LCase(oWshNetwork.UserName)
Session("Name") = oCurrentUser.FullName
Session("Computer") = LCase(oWshNetwork.ComputerName)

Select Case VarType(oCurrentUser.MemberOf)
    Case 8
        sGroups = LCase(oCurrentUser.MemberOf)
    Case 8204
        sGroups = LCase(Join(oCurrentUser.MemberOf))
End Select

If InStr(1, sGroups, "myApp_Users",1) Then
    Session("Auth") = 1
Else
    Session("Auth") = 0
End If

If InStr(1, sGroups, "myApp_Admins",1) Then
    Session("Admin") = 1
Else
    Session("Admin") = 0
End If

Set oWshNetwork = nothing
Set oADSysInfo = nothing
Set oCurrentUser = nothing

End If
```

I'm running these application in an Application pool with the Identity of a domain user.

This domain user has Read & Execute permissions to the application.

Kerberos delegation is enabled for each server:

```
Trust the computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)
```

I've configured SPNs for the domain user as follows:

```
http/myServer
http/myServer.mydomain.net
```

Yet when I run the app, my code falls over at the first GetObject call:

```
error '800704bc'
```

Can anybody help either debug this issue once and for all, or provide an alternative if there is one. Sure, I'd love to redevelop in .NET but that isn't an option.

Comment: Added the vbscript tag, if you want help with AD oriented script code the VBScript is the tag to have.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the meaning of your error:

```
C:\Users\BrianDesmond>err 0x800704bc
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x4bc
# for hex 0x4bc / decimal 1212
  ERROR_INVALID_DOMAINNAME                                       winerror.h
# The format of the specified domain name is invalid.
# 1 matches found for "0x800704bc"
```

With that in mind, what's getting passed to the first `GetObject()` call?

Also, unconstrained delegation, AKA "trust compute for delegation to any service" is a really bad security practice.

Comment: The LDAP string (generated from oADSysInfo.UserName) is 'LDAP://CN=My Name,OU=IT,OU=HQ,DC=mydomain,DC=net', where mydomain.net is the local AD domain. As far as I know, this is correct - it certainly works in some environments.

Comment: Re: unconstrained delegation, I take your point, but it's a case of getting things working. Ideally, I should tighten this up once a solution is found, but until then...

Comment: The returned value is the same on every server (as far as I know!), but the resulting call to GetObject fails on some, but not on others. Doesn't this suggest a Kerberos delegation issue?

Answer (score 0):

My situation resulting in this error was due to the `ADSystemInfo.UserName` method being invoked in the context of the service account.  This was that of the NetworkService (`NT_AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`) account and therefore local, and therefore not in the domain.  I'm guessing that's why in my case I got the `ERROR_INVALID_DOMAINNAME`.

In my case, a third party module was not providing the required user context, but more commonly I would expect that IIS authentication was misconfigured.